# Wildcard Number Search for thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

Can any one guide how to search number with wildcard on thinking sphinx...

I have tried, by using

```
User.search "12", :star => true
```

which result only 12
but i need to display the number whichever has 12. like prefix and suffix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled either min_infix_len or min_prefix_len, and enable_star? The documentation covers these settings in [a bit more detail](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#wildcards).